# After installing windows 10 on my ultrabook, it don't shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

As the title says, when I want to reboot or shutdown my ultrabook, it takes very long and still the lids on, (numpad and wifi leds). I can press caps lock to let that lid works though! I've googled and tried many things but couldn't find a solution! 
Any help please? 
my specs : 
Asus vivobook S551ln Core i7, 8gb ram on a x64 bit windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Event Viewer and try to identify the hardware/driver blocking shutdown. It should show up as an error at time of shutdown. I remember having such issues with Cisco VPN in Windows 8.

If updating drivers/components doesn't work, go to Power Settings and disable Fastboot. This reverts the changes they made between Windows 7 and 8/10 that screw up older drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my Dell laptop, although I don't remember if I solved this issue by installing all available drivers from dells website or if it was the fact that I reinstalled windows 10 in EFI (BIOS) mode rather than UEFI. I would reccomend you search the manufacturers website for compatible drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Management Engine Interface driver problem
Install the one present on support of s551ln in Windows 8.1

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin8.1/MEI/MEI_Intel_15M_Win81_64_VER9601038.zip?_ga=1.20784304.944951738.1457378626

Bye